# Dope sheet summary name part is hidden

Tags: dopesheet

[image][image: Does anyone know how I can get the name of my dope sheet things back up without restarting my entire file?]
Does anyone know how I can get the name of my dope sheet things back up without restarting my entire file?

The second picture is what happens when I press T. It didn't work sadly.

Comment: try pressing the Home key while the mouse is over the dope sheet and yes, I am clutching at straws

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just press the little + button

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>T</kbd> , and your panel should come up.